# Three columns with word-wrap inside but no line-break between the elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap, multiple-columns

I am trying to achieve the following Layout:

```
 +--------------------+  +-------------------+ +--------------------+ 
 | Right column with  |  | small center with | | Right column with  |
 | multiple lines and |  | fixed width       | | multiple lines and | 
 | width of           |  |                   | | width of           |
 | (100%-center)/2    |  |                   | | (100%-center)/2    |
 +--------------------+  +-------------------+ +--------------------+
```

but with my current markup, instead of introducing line-break inside the itself the right column will move below the rest once it's content becomes too big to fit the line:

```
 +--------------------+  +-------------------+ 
 | Right column with  |  | small center with | 
 | multiple lines and |  | fixed width       | 
 | width of           |  |                   | 
 | (100%-center)/2    |  |                   | 
 +--------------------+  +-------------------+ 

 +-------------------------------------------+ 
 | Right column with multiple lines and...   |
 +-------------------------------------------+
```

This is my current markup:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="float: left;">left</span>
    <span>center</span>
    <span style="float: right;">right</span>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the desired layout? Thanks!

Comment: Have you set width's for your span's ?

Comment: No, the left and the right spans should take all the available space (i.e. (100%-(width of center)) / 2)

Comment: no idea how to make it without defining center div, here it's in %: http://jsfiddle.net/UPwJ8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without modifying your markup:

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.container span {
    display: table-cell;
}

<div class="container">
    <span>left</span>
    <span>center</span>
    <span>right</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R3X4q/

Comment: I like not using a table, but the center is not always centered in that solution. Can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm interested and open for new and better ways.

Comment: Depends specifically what you mean by centered.  You can make the first and last spans the same width:  http://jsfiddle.net/R3X4q/1/.  Or you can use `text-align`:  http://jsfiddle.net/R3X4q/2/

Comment: The first jsfiddle is what I meant, but I don't know the width of the center cell. However, setting width to 50% for the left and the right cell worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: How would you do it, if the center would have a fixed pixel width? Say 200?

Comment: Not sure that it could be done with the center as a fixed width *and* perfectly centered when the first and last are unknown widths.  That might be doable with flexbox, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a table to me?

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="width:100%;border-spacing:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="float: left;">left</td>
            <td style=" width: 100px; margin: 0 auto auto auto;">center</td>
            <td style="float: right;">right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But it's not tabular data.

Comment: that's true, but it's the best solution so far

Comment: whats the difference? You could put anything within the table cells?

Comment: The difference is that the table tag is for tabular data.  Tables are not for layout.

Comment: You are right is not supposed to do layout, but if there is no equivalent?

Comment: some display: table; voodoo might be able to achieve the same without actually using tables, I guess.
@eactor the width in the center td misses the % sign.

Comment: I would use px for pixel if you like a fixed width

Comment: Actually there is a problem with this solution: the text in the left and right column gets wrapped even if that's not necessary space wise. Can this be fixed?

Comment: border-spacing:0px; for the table tag?